# can't resolve ... given input columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm going through the *Spark: The Definitive Guide* book from O'Reilly and I'm running into an error when I try to do a simple DataFrame operation.

The data is like:

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME,count
United States,Romania,15
United States,Croatia,1
...
```

I then read it with (in Pyspark):

```
flightData2015 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header","true").csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")
```

Then I try to run the following command:

```
flightData2015.select(max("count")).take(1)
```

I get the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`u`' given input columns: [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME, count];;
'Project ['u]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Relation[DEST_COUNTRY_NAME#10,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME#11,count#12] csv"
```

I don't know where "u" is even coming from, since it's not in my code and it isn't in the data file header either. I read another suggestion that this could be caused by spaces in the header, but that's not applicable here. Any idea what to try?

NOTE: The strange thing is, the same thing works when I use SQL instead of the DataFrame transformations. This works:

```
flightData2015.createOrReplaceTempView("flight_data_2015")
spark.sql("SELECT max(count) from flight_data_2015").take(1)
```

I can also do the following and it works fine:

```
flightData2015.show()
```

Comment: Are you able to select all the columns? What line endings are on the file?

Comment: I added a few more details to my question after "NOTE:"

Comment: As for the line endings, it has Unix line endings.

Comment: Hmm. BTW, you have 3 `u`'s in the header ;) Anyway, Spark version?

Comment: Oh also, I am doing all of this on MacOS, in case it matters. I know I have u's in the header, I just meant I have no "bare" u's. Anyway, my spark version is 2.3.1

Comment: Did you import `max` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` package?

Comment: It should be related to file's encoding. I just tried your code to reproduce the error with the files that i found in github and it's working fine. Here is the resource; https://github.com/databricks/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/tree/master/data/flight-data/csv Other than this, you could try to set the encoding or charset option while reading the csv but I am not sure which one would help and how since I don't have that csv file.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is that you are calling the built-in `max` function, not [`pyspark.sql.functions.max`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.max).

When python evaluates `max("count")` in your code it returns the letter `'u'`, which is the maximum value in the collection of letters that make up the string.

```python
print(max("count"))
#'u'
```

Try this instead:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
flightData2015.select(f.max("count")).show()
```