# Somewhat complex PySpark Select & Aggregate query

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark DataFrame with the following datatypes:

```python
print(df.dtypes)
[('TransactionDate', 'timestamp'), ('GroupByFld', 'int'), ('Amount', 'double'), 
('AdjustedTransactionDate', 'date')]
```

I want to do the equivalent of

`select min('AdjustedTransactionDate'),max('AdjustedTransactionDate'), GroupByFld, sum('Amount')`

I thought I could use Pyspark's dataframe api but even doing simple things such as:

```python
df.select(min("AdjustedTransactionDate"))
```

gives me the error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`A`' given input columns: [TransactionDate, GroupByFld, Amount, AdjustedTransactionDate];;

**Update:**

I ended up doing:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
df.groupBy('GroupByFld').agg(fn.min('adjTransactionDate').alias('MinTransactionDate'),fn.max('AdjTransactionDate').alias('MaxTransactionDate'),fn.sum('Amount').alias('Amount')).show()
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `pyspark.sql.functions.min` and not `__builtin__.min`?

Comment: I made an update -- still not correct but a little closer. See above.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. The pattern is `df.groupBy("GroupByFld").agg(*agg_fields)`. Try this: `df.groupBy('GroupByFld').agg(min('AdjustedTransactionDate'),max('AdjustedTransactionDate'),sum('Amount'))`. As as aside, importing `min`, `max`, and `sum` like that overwrites the builtin functions- I would recommend against doing that.

Comment: Thanks PaulIT. Doing that gives me the same issue &resolution as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719039/sum-operation-on-pyspark-dataframe-giving-typeerror-when-type-is-fine I guess I should import min/max without overwriting as the best solution?

Comment: I usually do `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`, and then I can call `f.min`, `f.max`, `f.sum`, etc when I want the API functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum operation on PySpark DataFrame giving TypeError when type is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719039/sum-operation-on-pyspark-dataframe-giving-typeerror-when-type-is-fine) or [can't resolve … given input columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757433/cant-resolve-given-input-columns/51769078#51769078). Your error message is because the `min` of `"AdjustedTransactionDate"` is `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first `groupBy` and then `agg` instead of `select`.

```
df.groupBy('GroupByFld')\
  .agg(min('AdjustedTransactionDate'),
       max('AdjustedTransactionDate'),
       sum('Amount'))
```

should do what you want.